# Firebase Function Error - Error: could not handle the request

Tags: function, firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const request = require('request');

exports.sendtest = functions.https.onRequest((requests, responses) => {
var id = 'test';
var num = 'test';

url='https://myurl.com/test.php?id='+id+'&num='+num;

request({
          url: url,
          method: 'get',
      }, function (error, response, body) {
          if (error) throw error;
          response.redirect(body);
      });

});
```

When I deploy and run the code I am getting error like

> Error: could not handle the request

I don't know why I am getting such error.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet to fix this problem? (there are multiple posts with this exact same error message floating around)

Comment: I copied and run the code in a separate js file using node command. It worked perfectly. But when I test in firebase it throws the error.

Comment: What does the functions log say in the Firebase console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because plan is free one. So it doesn't allow to connect outside google server.

Comment: Mine is on the Blaze plan, but I am still getting the error for requests outside the google server.